# Hibernate double level criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 classes.

Occupation.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "occupazione")
public class Occupazione implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * omitted the fields for brevity
     */

    private int idOccupation;
    private Posto posto;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_posto")
    public Posto getPosto() {
        return this.posto;
    }

    public void setPosto(Posto posto) {
        this.posto = posto;
    }
```

And Posto.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posti")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idPosto")
public class Posto implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idPosto;
    private Piano piano;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_piano")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Piano getPiano() {
        return piano;
    }

    public void setPiano(Piano piano) {
        this.piano = piano;
    }
```

Now, i want to retrieve all Occupation objects for a given Piano

I was doing this way

```
Criteria criteria = sess.getSession().createCriteria(Occupation.class).
                            createCriteria("posto").
        add(Restrictions.eq("piano", piano));

        return criteria.list();
```

but I'm getting this exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: posto of: it.besmart.models.Posto
```

But it's strange because `posto` should be referred to Occupation, not Posto itself...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
Criteria criteria = sess.getSession().createCriteria(Occupation.class).
                            createCriteria("posto").
        add(Restrictions.eq("piano", piano));
```

to

```
Criteria criteria = sess.getSession().createCriteria(Occupation.class).
        add(Restrictions.eq("piano", piano));
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work because `piano`it's not a property of Occupation.class `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: piano of: it.besmart.models.Occupation`

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it, it was easy made with `createAlias`...

```
Criteria criteria = sess.getSession().createCriteria(Occupation.class).
                            createAlias("posto", "p").
        add(Restrictions.eq("p.piano", piano));
```